# Convert Video to Frames in Python - 1 FPS

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, video-capture

I have a video that is 30 fps.
**I need to extract frames from the video at 1 FPS.** How is this possible in Python?

I have the below code I got from online but I am not sure if its extracting frames in 1 FPS.
Please help!

```
# Importing all necessary libraries 
import cv2 
import os 
  
# Read the video from specified path 
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\project_1\\openCV.mp4") 
  
try: 
      
    # creating a folder named data 
    if not os.path.exists('data'): 
        os.makedirs('data') 
  
# if not created then raise error 
except OSError: 
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data') 
  
# frame 
currentframe = 0
  
while(True): 
      
    # reading from frame 
    ret,frame = cam.read() 
  
    if ret: 
        # if video is still left continue creating images 
        name = './data/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
        print ('Creating...' + name) 
  
        # writing the extracted images 
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame) 
  
        # increasing counter so that it will 
        # show how many frames are created 
        currentframe += 1
    else: 
        break
  
# Release all space and windows once done 
cam.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You are not sure if it is executing in 1 FPS? What did you achieve on executing it?

Comment: I got frames from the video but I am not sure if it is happening at 1 FPS or 30 FPS

Answer (score 2):

```
KPS = 1# Target Keyframes Per Second
VIDEO_PATH = "video1.avi"#"path/to/video/folder" # Change this
IMAGE_PATH = "images/"#"path/to/image/folder" # ...and this 
EXTENSION = ".png"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_PATH)
fps = round(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
print(fps)
# exit()
hop = round(fps / KPS)
curr_frame = 0
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
ifnot ret: break
if curr_frame % hop == 0:
        name = IMAGE_PATH + "_" + str(curr_frame) + EXTENSION
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
    curr_frame += 1
cap.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use when I need to extract frames from videos:

```py
# pip install opencv-python

import cv2
import numpy as np

# video.mp4 is a video of 9 seconds
filename = "video.mp4"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO,0)
frameCount = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
frameWidth = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frameHeight = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
videoFPS = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

print (f"frameCount: {frameCount}")
print (f"frameWidth: {frameWidth}")
print (f"frameHeight: {frameHeight}")
print (f"videoFPS: {videoFPS}")

buf = np.empty((
    frameCount,
    frameHeight,
    frameWidth,
    3), np.dtype('uint8'))

fc = 0
ret = True

while (fc < frameCount):
    ret, buf[fc] = cap.read()
    fc += 1

cap.release()
videoArray = buf

print (f"DURATION: {frameCount/videoFPS}")
```

You can see how to extract features of the video like `frameCount`, `frameWidth`, `frameHeight`, `videoFPS`

At the end, the duration should be the number of frames divided by the `videoFPS` variable.

All the frames are stored inside `buf`, so if you want to extract only 1 Frame iterate over buf and extract only 9 frames (increasing your video FPS each iteration).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that I found works best.

```py
import os
import cv2
import moviepy.editor

def getFrames(vid, output, rate=0.5, frameName='frame'):
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
    clip = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(vid)

    seconds = clip.duration
    print('duration: ' + str(seconds))
    
    count = 0
    frame = 0
    
    if not os.path.isdir(output):
        os.mkdir(output)
    
    success = True
    while success:
        vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,frame*1000)      
        success,image = vidcap.read()

        ## Stop when last frame is identified
        print(frame)
        if frame > seconds or not success:
            break

        print('extracting frame ' + frameName + '-%d.png' % count)
        name = output + '/' + frameName + '-%d.png' % count # save frame as PNG file
        cv2.imwrite(name, image)
        frame += rate
        count += 1
```

The value for the `rate` argument is `1/fps`